# Using protractor typescript, how do i detect this element square white box, then click and drag the white box, it has ng-mousedown and transform

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor, webautomation

I need help in creating a typescript/javascript protractor code for this? for web automation.

How do I click on this whitebox and dragging it to left to right?

[image]

Dragging left to right, will also change the value of from `transform="translate(205)"` to `transform="translate(206)"` and also the `<text>2/20/18</text>`.

The web site code:

```
<g id="IndicateNav" ng-attr-trnsform="translate({{trVM._indicate || 0}})" ng-mousedown="trVM.mousedown($event, 'indicator')" ng-show="trVM._indicate" class="move-horizonal show-label-on-hover" transform="translate(205)">
   <line x1="0" x2="0" ng-attr-y1="{{trVM.bTop}}" ng-attr-y2="{{trVM.height}}" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" y1="20" y2="45"></line>
        <g ng-attr-trnsform="translate(0,{{trVM.bTop + ( (trVM.height - trVM.bTop) / 2) }})" transform="translate(0,32.5)">
            <square sx="0" sy="0" r="6" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" ng-non-bindable=""></square>
        </g>
            <text x="14" ng-attr-y="{{3 + trVM.bTop + ( (trVM.height-trVM.bTop) / 2 )}}" text-anchor="start" font-size="12px" fill="white" style="pointer-events:none;" y="35.5">2/20/18</text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of functions provided by `browser.actions()`.

### Solution:

1. Add id to `square` tag [Let's say the id is 'whiteBox'].
2. Get 'whiteBox' element and save it to a variable.

   ```
   const whiteBox = element(by.css('#whiteBox'));
   ```
3. Simulate the user's dragging behaviour by the following code:

   ```
   browser.actions().mouseDown(whiteBox).mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).mouseUp().perform()
   ```

   This will move drag the whiteBox to 50 pixels right.
4. If you want to drag 'whiteBox' to some other element, you can do that too:

   ```
   browser.actions().mouseDown(whiteBox).mouseMove(element2).mouseUp().perform()
   ```

---

### Complete Test Code:

```
describe('whiteBox Dragging Test', function() {
  it('Drag whiteBox to right', function () {
    const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    const whiteBox = element(by.css('#whiteBox'));
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(whiteBox), 5000).then(() => {
      browser.actions().mouseDown(whiteBox).mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).mouseUp().perform();
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: A quick note: The Actions API has changed / will be be changing soon. This statement is based on if library or browser driver has implemented the W3C actions standard. Protractor is currently using selenium-webdriver 3 (pre-W3C standard) and some browser drivers like gecko might not work (with W3C standard)

Comment: @Saddam its not working, it has an error: "Failed:Wait timed out after 10069ms"

Comment: @SeanRay The code where you have mentioned a timeout of 10 seconds (i.e. 10000 ms) failed. That's why it is showing that error. Also, a similar error can be thrown by my code which will say `"Failed:Wait timed out after 5000ms"` if whiteBox element is not present in the browser within 5 seconds.

Comment: @SeanRay, You mean you want to change some input text box value?

Comment: @SaddamPojee i already figure out how to move the squarebox but i also need to change the value on text. ['code'] browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(whiteBox), 5000).then(() => {
           whiteBox.getAttribute('transform').then(() =>{
               browser.driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('IndicateNav').setAttribute('transform','translate(600)')");
      }); ['code']

Comment: the text "2/20/18" in this part of the code:
 <text x="14" ng-attr-y="{{3 + trVM.bTop + ( (trVM.height-trVM.bTop) / 2 )}}" text-anchor="start" font-size="12px" fill="white" style="pointer-events:none;" y="35.5">2/20/18</text>

Comment: @SeanRay But as you mentioned in the question, that dragging from left to right will also change the transform value. Then the above code snippet example of `browser.actions()` should solve your issue.

Comment: yes i've tried the sliding code that you provided but it just won't work, i also like to have that, but i'd just want to have to this as alternative i guess, until i figure out how to slide that

Comment: @SeanRay Have you tried explicitly finding element again in `browser.actions()` like `browser.actions().mouseDown(element(by.css('#whiteBox'))).mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).mouseUp().perform();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186052/discussion-between-saddam-pojee-and-seanray).

Comment: still haven't, proposed solution requires changes on the web source code, still looking for other ways if web source code is not changed

Comment: @SeanRay but in the chat, I showed 1 more approach if you are unable to modify web source code.

Comment: it works but website source code needs to be modified